# Convert float to ushort

Tags: c#, ushort

I am new to C sharp, and i am trying to do the following but getting an error as not able to convert short to ushort

```
double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text) * 10;
ushort offsetIDWrite = Convert.ToInt16(x);
```

Comment: `ToInt16` --> `ToUInt16`

Comment: `ushort offsetIDWrite = (ushort)x;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `ushort offsetIDWrite = Convert.ToUInt16(x);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ushort offsetIDWrite = Convert.ToUInt16(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lost of significant data is considerable with the two lines displayed.

the textbox should be validated as part of the  conversion.

```
  try {
        ushort number = UInt16.Parse(textbox6.text);
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> {1}", textbox6.text, number);
     }
     catch (FormatException) {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> Bad Format", textbox6.text);
     }
     catch (OverflowException) {   `enter code here`
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> OverflowException", textbox6.text);
     }
     catch (ArgumentNullException) {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' --> Null", textbox6.text);
     }
```